# Adding a condition clause to an R command, to change the group an individual has been placed in

Tags: r

This is sort of a follow-up question to my previous question here: [Making a new column in R based on results of previous columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660156/making-a-new-column-in-r-based-on-results-of-previous-columns)

So I managed to create 4 groups based on two columns of previous data as shown using this code:

```
transform(dat1, group = factor(1 + 2*Choice1 + Choice2))
```

There are also a number of dates associated with Choice 1 and Choice 2. Am example of this is shown below:

```
Choice1        Choice2        Choice1Date    Choice2Date    DOI
TRUE           TRUE           1970-01-01     1970-01-01     1980-01-01
TRUE           TRUE           1970-02-02     1980-02-02     1975-02-02
TRUE           TRUE           1980-03-03     1980-03-03     1970-03-03
TRUE           TRUE           1980-04-04     1970-04-04     1975-04-04
TRUE           FALSE          1970-05-05     NA             1980-05-05
FALSE          TRUE           NA             1970-06-06     1980-06-06
FALSE          FALSE          NA             NA             1980-07-07
FALSE          TRUE           NA             1980-08-08     1970-08-08
```

The above code codes each of these individuals in the following groups: 4,4,4,4,3,2,1,3.

I've been trying to now add a condition to the above statement where if Choice1Date>DOI and Choice2Date>DOI then the individual will be classed as group 1 and not group 4.
If an individual is classed as Choice1Date>DOI but Choice2Date<DOI, then they should be classed as group 3 and not group 4.
If an individual is classed as Choice1DateDOI, then they are classed as group 2 and not group 4.
Consequently if Choice1Date<DOI and Choice2Date<DOI then they are group 4.

This should change the above groups to: 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1.

To do this I've tried getting the following line to run after my above code:

```
if((dat1$DOI<dat1$Choice1Date) & (dat1$DOI<dat1$Choice2Date)) <- dat1$group=1
```

I was going to repeat something similar for the remaining requirements but this above code doesn't work.
I can't work out what I need to do to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried having a look through other forums and how to use the if command in R but nothing has so far helped

Comment: Is there missing an operator? If an individual is classed as Choice1DateDOI, then they are classed as group 2 and not group 4.

Comment: `The above code codes each of these individuals in the following groups: 4,4,4,4,2,3,1,3.` This is not correct? I get `4,4,4,4,3,2,1,2`

Comment: Whoops, apologies, mixed up numbers 2 and 3 the wrong way around when I was writing out the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First character `date` to a date with `lubridate` then you can compare.
- Then `mutate` a new column `group_new` with your conditions. Where the third condition is not clear but a guess.
- In case conditions are not complete you can add.
- The only thing that keeps open is how you handle `NAs` one column or both?
- In the code further down we use the pre-existing group `TRUE ~ as.character(group)`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# your data
dat1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Choice1,  ~Choice2,  ~Choice1Date, ~Choice2Date,   ~DOI,
  TRUE,     TRUE,      "1970-01-01",  "1970-01-01",    "1980-01-01",
  TRUE,     TRUE,      "1970-02-02",  "1980-02-02",    "1975-02-02",
  TRUE,     TRUE,      "1980-03-03",  "1980-03-03",    "1970-03-03",
  TRUE,     TRUE,      "1980-04-04",  "1970-04-04",    "1975-04-04",
  TRUE,     FALSE,     "1970-05-05",  NA,              "1980-05-05",
  FALSE,    TRUE,      NA,            "1970-06-06",    "1980-06-06",
  FALSE,    FALSE,     NA,            NA,              "1980-07-07",
  FALSE,    TRUE,      NA,            "1980-08-08",    "1970-08-08")

## your conditions
# Choice1Date>DOI and Choice2Date>DOI then the individual will be clasgroup 1 and not group 4. 
# Choice1Date>DOI but Choice2Date<DOI, then they should be classed as group 3 and not group 4. 
# Choice1DateDOI, then they are classed as group 2 and not group 4. 
# Choice1Date<DOI and Choice2Date<DOI then they are group 4.


df <- transform(dat1, group = factor(1 + 2*Choice1 + Choice2))

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(Choice1Date = ymd(Choice1Date),
         Choice2Date = ymd(Choice2Date),
         DOI = ymd(DOI)) %>% 
  mutate(group_new = case_when(Choice1Date > DOI & Choice2Date > DOI ~ "1",
                           Choice1Date > DOI & Choice2Date < DOI ~ "3",
                           Choice1Date < DOI & Choice2Date < DOI ~ "4",
                           Choice1Date < DOI & Choice2Date > DOI ~ "2",
                           TRUE ~ as.character(group))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `case_when` from {dplyr}. It looks confusing
at first but it is very intuitive. If you are not well versed with
{dplyr} just call `vignette("dplyr")` from R.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1 %>% 
    mutate(
        group = case_when(
            Choice1 & Choice2 & (DOI < Choice1Date) & (DOI < Choice2Date) ~ 1,  
            !Choice1 & Choice2 & (DOI < Choice1Date) & (DOI > Choice2Date) ~ 2,  
            # use !Choice1 for for negating FALSE to TRUE 

            
            TRUE ~ NA_real_ # 
            # read "TRUE ~ NA" as "otherwise missing". NA_real_ so that it 
            # matches the data type given above. you can also give 
            # TRUE ~ 0, or TRUE ~ -1 or for all values that does not 
            # match any of the above conditions, or even TRUE ~ group, 
            # if you are only modifying some values and keeping the rest as is.
    )
)
```

### data

```r
dat1 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Choice1,  ~Choice2,  ~Choice1Date, ~Choice2Date,   ~DOI,
    TRUE,     TRUE,      "1970-01-01",  "1970-01-01",    "1980-01-01",
    TRUE,     TRUE,      "1970-02-02",  "1980-02-02",    "1975-02-02",
    TRUE,     TRUE,      "1980-03-03",  "1980-03-03",    "1970-03-03",
    FALSE,     TRUE,      "1980-04-04",  "1970-04-04",    "1975-04-04",
    TRUE,     FALSE,     "1970-05-05",  NA,            "1980-05-05",
    FALSE,    TRUE,      NA,          "1970-06-06",    "1980-06-06",
    FALSE,    FALSE,     NA,          NA,            "1980-07-07",
    FALSE,    TRUE,      NA,          "1980-08-08",    "1970-08-08"
) %>% mutate(
    across(contains("Date"), .fns = as.Date))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on exactly the conditions and, in particular, the conditions would need to clarify how to handle NA values, but aside from the exact conditions, for the code statement shown in the question this will overwrite the group value with 1 in those rows satisfying the indicated condition.  There can be as many statements as desired of this sort within the {...}.  Whether a value is NA or not can be checked using `is.na`.

```
within(dat1, {
   group <- factor(1 + 2*Choice1 + Choice2)
   group[DOI < Choice1Date & DOI < Choice2Date] <- 1
   # other conditions
})
```

If the intent was not to overwrite every row satisfying the condition but only to overwrite those rows which were in group 4 prior to applying the condition then the above statement would be written as shown below.

We have added group0 which is the original value of group.  It is not used in the code below but we added it in case some of the conditions that you add require the original value of group instead of the value after being modified by the intervening statements. At the end we assign NULL to it which removes it.

```
within(dat1, {
   group0 <- group <- factor(1 + 2*Choice1 + Choice2)
   group[group == 4 & DOI < Choice1Date & DOI < Choice2Date] <- 1
   # other conditions
   group0 <- NULL
})
```